# Limits explanation in doc

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, documentation

`Limit[expr,x->Subscript[x, 0],Direction->1]` computes the limit as x approaches `Subscript[x, 0]` from smaller values. `Limit[expr,x->Subscript[x, 0],Direction->-1]` computes the limit as x approaches `Subscript[x, 0]` from larger values.

This to me is confusing, I though x->4- that x are approaching xo from smaller values, in other words from the left hand side. Why would one therefore use 1 for left hand side and -1 for right hand side. Do not see the logic

Comment: Approaching direction corresponds to the direction of axis for example.

Comment: Think of it as the direction you're going, not the direction you're coming from. (Although I do agree with you that it is a little inconsistent with the traditional mathematical notation. Perhaps they should have just used `Above` and `Below` for no chance of confusion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as the direction you're going, not the direction you're coming from. (Although I do agree with you that it is a little inconsistent with the traditional mathematical notation. Perhaps they should have just used `Above` and `Below` for no chance of confusion.)

Comment: "Above" and "Below" would be problematic when discussing unreal (surreal?) approaches in the complex plane.